# Jackson to include 'class' field when serializing object to json

Tags: json, jackson

I need my Grails app to communicate (JSON) with client that uses Jackson. By default Grails include 'class' in the generated json. On the other hand, default Jackson's `ObjectMapper` doesn't recognize 'class', it throws error.

I've found solution, by adding `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")` on each POJO classes that are being used.

But, I don't prefer that approach. Because now my POJO will have dependency to Jackson's jar. Is there another easy alternative?

I was trying to figure out from `objectMapper.getSerializationConfig(). ...`, but still couldn't found the alternative to replace that annotation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the type info for polymorphic instantiation or are you ignoring that information? You could probably use instead `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"class"})` on your classes.

If you really don't want to add annotation to your classes, you can use the mix-in mechanism. Although it is much more easier to add the annotation directly to your classes, if you control the classes of course.

```
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(YourClass.class, TypeInfoMixIn.class);
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(YourSecondClass.class, TypeInfoMixIn.class);
// etc.

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public class TypeInfoMixIn {}
```

Comment: I didn't have control over the classes so this addMixInAnnotations will be useful. thanks.